# .net ajax toolkit on server doesnt work

Tags: asp.net

Im developing a ASP 3.5 Website and I Like put some ajax on it.

Everythings works like a charm on my machine but when I upload it to the server doesnt work. Example:

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="TextBox1_CalendarExtender" runat="server" 
        Enabled="True" TargetControlID="TextBox1">
    </asp:CalendarExtender>
</div>
</form>
```

I have the `<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>` as second line and the AjaxControlToolkit.dll inside bin directory

Before y get the error `<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">` is unknow but I added the following line to my web.config

```
      <pages>
    <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" />
```

and no errors, but only see a textbox, the calendar doesnt work.

I read a lot of pages and I can't find the solution. Thanks in advance

I read

> Apparently I had to install the ajax web extensions on the production server.  I originally thought that simply having the ajaxtoolkit.dll and pdb in the bin folder was all that was needed.  Not so.  Need to install the Ajaxsetup.msi on the production server.

It is true? A simple scriptmanager with updatepanel works, but nothing with toolkit !!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the ASP.NET ScriptManager. Check this link out
http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/Using-the-ASP-NET-AJAX-ScriptManager.id-305492.html

Comment: But if I put ScriptManager the calendar doesnt work in localhost and in the server neither :(

Comment: I hadn't noticed you were using the ToolkitScriptManager, have you added the AjaxControlToolkit in the assemblies list in your web.config?